# Did Sharepoint 2016 misspell 'aria-expanded' for its list header sort arrow links?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, accessibility

I was performing an accessibility review of our website and I found that there were many invalid aria attributes all over the place.  Upon closer inspection, it appears that any list has an `<a>` tag (with the class .ms-headerSortArrowLink) with an attribute aria-expended='false'.  Unless I am mistaken, there is no attribute aria-expended and only an aria-expanded.  Did they just make a typo?

I loaded up a fresh test on-premises 2016 sharepoint site, created a custom list and can verify that the misspelling is still there.  It's also present for the default pages library.

I guess I could run some custom jQuery to clean it up like so:

```
$("a.ms-headerSortArrowLink").removeAttr("aria-expended");
$("a.ms-headerSortArrowLink").attr("aria-expanded", "false");
```

Does anyone else have this issue and are there any better ways of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is client side logic in SharePoint, I can't confirm its'misspelling, you could override the JS function(RenderDVTHeaderField) if you want to do this, while I think you'd better submit your feedback for this to Microsoft.

For overriding JS function, check [here](http://decro.net/article/how-easily-override-javascript-function)

[image]